# How can I vertically center a title on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to make a design like at the picture:
[image: requaered design]

as you can see, at the top bar of the screen there is a title at the center. I can set it to horizontal center, but how to set it to vertical center?

I allready tryed:

- override RichTextField to make it custom sized. it works for widht, but not height.
- override horizontal/vertical field manager to make it with custon height with vertical centrizing, but it didn't work:

  ```
      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
      HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER){
          protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
          {
              super.sublayout( Display.getWidth(), 50);
          }
      };
      LabelWithCustomSize title = new LabelWithCustomSize("ENTERTAINMENT",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE,Display.getWidth(),50,30,2);
      hfm.add(title);
      vfm.add(hfm);
  ```
- add an empty RichTextField with small text size, but fiels allways has same height.

**How to set text or any other field at vertical center?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you will need to solve is "How does a Manager centre vertically and Horizontally any field that is added to it". Trying to solve this problem for N number of fields added to Manager might be a bit involved but just for one field, it must be quite easy. I suggest you try this :

```
 VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(){
        public void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
        {
            int margin = 0;
            int lheight = 0;
            Field f = getField( 0 );
            margin = f.getMarginBottom()+f.getMarginTop();
            layoutChild(f, maxWidth-margin, maxHeight);
            int w = f.getWidth();
            int h = f.getHeight();
            lheight = h+margin;
            int x = (maxWidth - w)/2;
            int y = (maxHeight -h)/2;
            setPositionChild( f, x, y);
            setExtent( maxWidth, lheight);
        }
    };
    vfm.add( field);
```

Comment: something wrong with your code: f (Field) does not have setPositionChild method. I tryed "this" and without "f", but in all cases there was no field aapeared.

Comment: Oops! sorry setPositionChild is available with the Manager. I am editing the answer

Comment: thenks for response, but I allready tryed it. setPositionChild( f,x,y); is equal to this.setPositionChild( f,x,y); as I know... I thyed both of this, just in case, but as I sad, there was no field apeared

Comment: You calculated `lheight` wrong. but I fixed it, and it finaly warked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What was the fix? Anyways, I was trying to drive the correct direction than solve the problem; time crunch. Thanks that it was useful

Comment: well, technically it wasn't "fix". I checked this value. in my case it was 27, so text was hided at half. I just setted it to 50, and text become visiable.